# How can I set an id with characters in phpmyadmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin

See, I have 3 different list I need to upload to my database, but they need to be set an ID such as "JA-0001, UP-0001, ST-0001" and on.

Comment: Why? I mean you make a database data table for let's say Customers.
Customer can have an i_d named as c_id, auto increment and no string letters will be used. Instead there will be just numbers. Why would you want to have such a key instead of just a simple number?(not my rate down I wait for your answer here)

Comment: It's not for users. I have about 600 items in 3 different lists I need to store in a database. For each, I need an ID and specify which list they are from.

Comment: Just a pain. I can't recommend you something as good practice, since what will be best practice depends heavily on what is the nature and relations of these lists and if you need to maintain the current encoding. Is is possible to just make three different tables? Or do you wanna merge them together? You might need a complex primary key, consisted by two parts maybe. It is called  composite key, you can google how to do it but still I am not sure what to recommend you here so I have to apologize and pass this to a more experienced professional. It seems that Mr Joop already suggested something

Comment: Maybe, if you give me more details (like exactly what kind of data are to be stored, like "I want to store spare parts of an engine my employer assembles and sells and we got in stock with serial numbers for each one and blah blah blah" and then tell me how these data were stored in the past into these three lists and what the existing new database looks or will look like I might give you a solution.Actually is there a new database or are you hired to re-engineer the whole thing?) Finally, please tell me what is the puropose of doing this merge. Maybe you don't have to.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could make tables T_JA, T_UP, T_ST with an **autoincrememt** field, and have in the main table an internal **autoincrement** key, and some nullable reference fields, FK_JA, FK_UP, FK_ST, and maybe a enum field with JA/UP/ST.

That might seem (even be) ugly, but would be a canonical normalized model.

A virtual (calculated) field in the table or view the could hold your combined ID.

Comment: Why do you believe that one attribute would justify this model? Even if products are not compatible and must be specialized I would resist a lot before moving from a STI (Single Table Inheritance) to a MTI (Multiple Table Inheritance) strategy. The normalized model, however, would include a source or supplier table with a FK on product referencing supplier.

Comment: @Inrdo you are right, inheritance I rejected too. I did not mean inheritance, T_JA is just a table to get a separate sequence number, one column. In Oracle one would do it differently. Nice seeing your answer, as N tables T_:XX / N fields FK_XX is ugly. I think **numbering** is a lousy idea here.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you need a composite key?

Table product_source with a source_code varchar(2) primary key.

Table product with a primary key composed by source_code varchar(2) and external_id int(4) unsigned ZEROFILL not null, along with a foreign key on product (source_code) referencing product_source (source_code).

Your primary key will be XX-9999.